# Binding two fields of an object from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

So I have an class called`CustomerCollection`

```
class CustomerCollection
    {
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }
...
}
```

that has a list of `customers`

```
class Customer
{
    public String ID { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public Customer(String id, String name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there away to bind a combo box and a text box such that the combobox will display all the possible ids of `Customers` in `Customer Collection` and the textbox will display the name of the chosen customer?

EDIT:
So here's what I've tried

```
    private void InitializeCustomerCollection()
    {
        var customerCollection = new CustomerCollection();
        cmbx_custID.DataSource = customerCollection.Customers;
    }
```

But that doesn't work and results the combobox being filled with

```
X.Collections.Customer
X.Collections.Customer
X.Collections.Customer
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What platform are you using? WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Winform. I forgotten to tag it as such. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish this in WinForms. However, the reason why you are seeing the output like you have shown, is because it doesn't know how to display your current object. You either need to provide it with a DisplayMemberPath (this is what it would be in xaml/wpf) or overload the class .ToString() method to use the Name of your Customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This demonstrates adding a combo box to a form with the behavior you describe. The key is setting ValueMember and DisplayMember.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomerCollection cc = new CustomerCollection();
        cc.Customers.AddRange(new Customer[] {new Customer("1", "Adam"), new Customer("2", "Bob")});

        ComboBox ComboBox1 = new ComboBox()
           {Name = "ComboBox1", ValueMember = "ID", DisplayMember = "Name"};
        Controls.Add(ComboBox1);

        ComboBox1.DataSource = cc;
     }
  }

  public class Customer
  {
     public String ID { get; private set; }
     public String Name { get; private set; }

     public Customer(String id, String name)
     {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
     }
  }

  class CustomerCollection : IListSource
  {
     public List<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }
     public CustomerCollection()
     {
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
     }

     public bool ContainsListCollection
     {
        get { return true; }
     }

     public System.Collections.IList GetList()
     {
        return Customers;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you can do something like the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource={Binding Customers} x:Name="SelectedComboBox"/>
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=SelectedComboBox/>
```